# How to destroy C# data like Dictionary<string, List<Action<object>>>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates

I defined an object like `Dictionary<string, List<Action<object>>>` to store some delegate methods to invoke. If I wanna destroy this Dictionary. Should I need to call `List.Clear()` first in Dictionary? Or just call `Dictionary.Clear` will be ok?

This one:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<Action<object>>> kvp in dict)
{
   kvp.Value.Clear();
}

dict.Clear();
dict = null;
```

Or this one:

```
dict.Clear();
dict = null;
```

Comment: Works the second one? If yes, use that else use the first one.

Comment: You just need `dict = null;` - nothing else. Not even the `dict.Clear();`. You don't even need the `dict = null;` if the variable is going out of scope.

Comment: Although clearing things explicitly may sound natural if you come from C background, C#'s garbage collection system takes care of freeing resources when they are no longer necessary, letting you spend more time coding the core parts of your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are about to drop the last live reference to `dict`, don't bother with any of it: simply assign `null` if `dict` remains in scope, or don't do anything if the scope of `dict` is about to end.

Explicit clearing of the dictionary or any of the lists that it contains is not required, because garbage collector would take care of it either way. Explicit clearing of the dictionary and the lists it contains would be a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: If the delegates stored in the List of Dictionary came from outside. Call Clear method is necessary?

Comment: @JerryLee It does not matter where the delegates came from. If you do not plan to reuse the dictionary or the list, don't call `Clear()` on it.

Comment: So you means, even though the Dictionary hold some delegates, just set it null, GC will collect it? right?

Comment: @JerryLee Yes, that is correct. As long as there are no other live references to your dictionary, e.g. from other threads, GC will collect the dictionary, its internals, its lists, and list's delegates.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the doubt in my mind a long time!

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't have a reference on the objects stored in the `Dictionary` or the `Dictionary` itself, you can just set it to `null`.

```
dict = null;
```

`GC` will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

this alone will do. Clearing the reference of the dictionary is needed only if it is declared at global level. Local objects are not needed to be cleared.

```
    dict = null;
```

As long as reference of the object is cleared it will be cleared from memory on next GC of that generation.